# c# Create several xdocuments from xelements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Is it easily possible to create a new xdocument from a xelement?
I have a large xml-file and i want to create several xdocuments out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string xml = "<Root><Child1>aaa</Child1><Child2>bbb</Child2></Root>";

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var xDocs = xDoc.Root.Elements()
    .Select(e => new XDocument(e))
    .ToList();
```

This example creates two xDocuments containing Child1 and Child2